# Select inner parentheses nested inside other parentheses

Tags: c#, regex, nested

How can I use regular expressions to extract a series of text within a set of parentheses - specifically, when those parentheses themselves are nested inside one or more sets of parentheses.  For example:

**Input:**

```
_t("someText (I don't want to wear pajamas.)")
```

**Output:**

```
(I don't want to wear pajamas.)
```

Comment: Post your attempt/code for the problem please. Also, read the [FAQ about how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

You could use this regex

```
\([^()]*\)
```

---

```
List<string> output=Regex.Matches(input,aboveRegex)
                         .Cast<Match>()
                         .Select(x=>x.Value)
                         .ToList();
```